# C Program to Mark as "Min" and "Max" from the array elements and print on the min/max corresponding location column on console

Tags: arrays, c, console, printf

I am trying to label Min and Max that will correspond to the int Min & Max number, for example:

```
Serial No.     Min/Max  
1                Min
2
3
4
5                Max
```

At the console, other columns are printing as per my requirement but can't get this "Min/Max" column printed as above.

My code for this part as follows:

```
int max = userArray[0];
int min = userArray[0];
for(i=1; i<=10; i++){
    //excluded codes to print other columns  

    //code for my concerned column print
    if(userArray[i]>max){
        max = userArray[i];
    }
    if(userArray[i]==max){
        printf("%49s\n","Max");  
    }
    if(min > userArray[i]){
        min = userArray[i];
    }
    if(userArray[i]==min){
        printf("%49s\n","Min");  
    }
}
```

Comment: Really unsure about what you are trying to do here. Can you give more details ?

Comment: What is the significance of the loop `for(i=1; i<=10; i++)`? How many elements are there in the array (only 5 are shown) and what happened with element [0]? Why is the code to print other columns omitted, when you have an alignment issue? What *is* that alignment issue? Why `%49s`? Also, you need to separate the min/max determination from the output loop. You can't know if line 1 was the max value until you have reached the bottom.

Comment: `if(userArray[i]==max)` You probably need to have that and the corresponding `min` check *outside* the loop. That is, you need to finish the loop before deciding which is the final max/min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't find and print min and max while you are printing the other columns. Simply because you can't know what min and max are until you have looked at all elements.

You need to find min and max **before** you start the print-loop. So you need an additional loop.

```
// Find index of min and max values
int max_idx = 0;
int min_idx = 0;
int max = userArray[max_idx];
int min = userArray[min_idx];
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    if (userArray[i]>max)
    {
        max_idx = i;
        max = userArray[max_idx];
    }
    else if (userArray[i] < min)
    {
        min_idx = i;
        min = userArray[min_idx];
    }
}

// Now do the print
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    //excluded codes to print other columns  

    if(i == max_index && i == min_index)
    {
        printf("%49s\n","Min/Max");  
    }
    else if(i == max_index)
    {
        printf("%49s\n","Max");  
    }
    else if(i == min_index){
        printf("%49s\n","Min");  
    }
}
```

Notice that the use of `min_index` and `max_index` ensures that e.g. Max is only printed once even when the maximum value occurs multiple times.

Answer (score -1):

You need to complete the loop once before printing `min` or `max` to identify the `min` and `max` values.

```c
int main()
{
        int userArray[10] = {3, 2, 1, 4, 6, 5, 7, 8, 10, 9};
        int max = userArray[0];
        int min = userArray[0];
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
                //excluded codes to print other columns
                //code for my concerned column print
                if(userArray[i]>max){
                        max = userArray[i];
                }

                if(userArray[i] < min){
                        min = userArray[i];
                }

        }
        printf("Serial No.\tMin/Max\n");
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
                printf("%d\t", userArray[i]);
                if(userArray[i] == min)
                        printf("\tMin");
                if(userArray[i] == max)
                        printf("\tMax");
                printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
}
```

prints the desired columns

```
Serial No.      Min/Max
3
2
1               Min
4
6
5
7
8
10              Max
9
```